# WebHCat on Amazon's EMR?

Tags: amazon-web-services, hive, emr

Is it possible or advisable to run [WebHCat](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/WebHCat) on an Amazon Elastic MapReduce cluster?

I'm new to this technology and I was wonder if it was possible to use WebHCat as a REST interface to run Hive queries. The cluster in question is running Hive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to get it working but WebHCat is actually installed by default on Amazon's EMR instance.

To get it running you have to do the following,

```
chmod u+x /home/hadoop/hive/hcatalog/bin/hcat
chmod u+x /home/hadoop/hive/hcatalog/sbin/webhcat_server.sh
export TEMPLETON_HOME=/home/hadoop/.versions/hive-0.11.0/hcatalog/
export HCAT_PREFIX=/home/hadoop/.versions/hive-0.11.0/hcatalog/
/home/hadoop/hive/hcatalog/webhcat_server.sh start
```

You can then confirm that it's running on port 50111 using curl,

```
curl -i http://localhost:50111/templeton/v1/status
```

To hit 50111 on other machines you have to open the port up in the EC2 EMR security group.

You then have to configure the users you going to "proxy" when you run queries in hcatalog. I didn't actually save this configuration, but it is [outlined in the WebHCat documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/WebHCat+InstallWebHCat#WebHCatInstallWebHCat-Permissions). I wish they had some concrete examples there but basically I ended up configuring the local 'hadoop' user as the one that run the queries, not the most secure thing to do I am sure, but I was just trying to get it up and running.

Attempting a query then gave me this error,

> {"error":"Server IPC version 9 cannot communicate with client version
>   4"}

The workaround was to switch off of the latest EMR image (3.0.4 with Hadoop 2.2.0) and switch to a Hadoop 1.0 image (2.4.2 with Hadoop 1.0.3).

I then hit another issues where it couldn't find the Hive jar properly, after struggling with the configuration more, I decided I had dumped enough time into trying to get this to work and decided to communicate with Hive directly (using RBHive for Ruby and JDBC for the JVM).

To answer my own question, it is possible to run WebHCat on EMR, but it's not documented at all (Googling lead me nowhere which is why I created this question in the first place, it's currently the first hit when you search "WebHCat EMR") and the WebHCat documentation leaves a lot to be desired. Getting it to work seems like a pain, though my hope is that by writing up the initial steps someone will come along and take it the rest of the way and post a complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

I did not test it but, it should be doable.

EMR allows to customise the bootstrap actions, i.e. the scripts run where the nodes are started.  You can use bootstrap actions to install additional software and to change the configuration of applications on the cluster
See more details at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-plan-bootstrap.html.

I would create a shell script to install WebHCat and test your script on a regular EC2 instance first (outside the context of EMR - just as a test to ensure your script is OK)

You can use EC2's [user-data properties](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html) to test your script, typically :

`#!/bin/bash
curl http://path_to_your_install_script.sh | sh`

Then - once you know the script is working - make it available to the cluster on a S3 bucket and [follow these instructions to include your script](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-plan-bootstrap.html#CustombootstrapConsole) as custom bootstrap action of your cluster.

--Seb